# Avoid some query fields from filtering results

Tags: feathersjs

When I make a GET request to a service with a query string as in `/restaurants?includeData`, by default `includeData` is used to filter the restaurants giving me zero results.

How can I avoid this specific query field from being used in the filtering so that I can use it for my own purposes in a hook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create another `before` hook that modifies the `hook.params.query` and `hook` object to what you need:

```
app.service('myservice').before(function(hook) {
  hook.includeData = hook.params.query.includeData;

  delete hook.params.query.includeData;
});
```